# With continue chain, how to achieve absolute node positioning?

Tags: tikz-chains

My problem is that I want to draw several horizontal "layers" of nodes (implemented as chains), with connections between them.  When I try to position a node absolutely, it is additionally offset in the chain's direction:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1,
  block/.style={
    on chain,
    inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    draw,minimum height=10,minimum width=2}
]

\path[start chain=layer1]
  node[block] {}
  node[block,join] {}
  node[block,join] {}
;

\path[start chain=layer2]
  node[block,join=with layer1-3,below=of layer1-end] {}
  node[block,join] {}
  node[block,join] {}
;

%\path[start chain=layer1right] % WORKS
\path[continue chain=layer1]    % DOES NOT WORK, BUT WHY?
  node[block,join=with layer2-end,anchor=center] at (layer2-end |- layer1-end) {}
  node[block,join] {}
  node[block,join] {}
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried variants like

```
node[block,join=with layer2-end placed {at=(layer2-end |- layer1-end)},anchor=center] {}
```

and **I don't understand why I get the additional offset** (I did find a workaround, see below).  According to the pgfmanual, I think this should've worked:

> Independently of which form is used, the ⟨text⟩ inside ⟨direction⟩ that follows going or placed (separated by a compulsory space) can have two different effects:
>
> (a) If it contains an equal sign, then this ⟨text⟩ is used as the placement rule, that is, it is simply executed.
>
> (b) If it does not contain an equal sign, then ⟨text⟩=of \tikzchainprevious is used as the placement rule.
>
> Note that in the first case, inside the ⟨text⟩ you have access to \tikzchainprevious and \tikzchaincount for doing your positioning calculations.

My workaround (see commented out code) is to start a new chain (which has the additional advantage that I could remove the `anchor=center`).  I cannot use `above=of ...`, because in my real code, the blocks have different heights, and the nodes on layer1 will not be aligned anymore.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: Can you simply indicate where you like to have start of continuation of `layer1` chain? Above end of `layer2`? Or on an arbitrary place?

Comment: Yes, horizontically aligned with the end of layer2, and vertically aligned with layer1, exactly as expressed by the `at (...)`.  If you uncomment the "WORKS" line, and comment out the "DOES NOT WORK" line, you can also see the intended result.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for the heads-up, I edited the code. (I am using a script that allows me to view such .tikz files, so for me it already was a MWE.)

Comment: See, if this help: `\path[continue chain=layer1]   [block,join=with layer2-end,above=of layer2-end] {}   node[block,join] {}
  node[block,join] {};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would:

- set up `layer2` as a `branch`;
- add the precisely positioned node outside the chain;
- use `\chainin` to add that node into the chain before continuing with the remaining nodes.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    node distance=1,
    basic block/.style={%
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      draw,
      minimum height=10,
      minimum width=2,
    },
    block/.style={%
      basic block,
      on chain,
    },
    start chain=layer1,
  ]
  \path
  node [block] {}
  node [block,join,minimum height=20] {}
  node [block,join,minimum height=5] {}
  ;
  {[start branch=layer2 going below]
    \node [block,join,minimum height=20] {};
  }
  {[continue branch=layer2 going right]
    \path
    node [block,join] {}
    node [block,join,minimum height=30] {}
    ;
  }
  \node (a) [basic block] at (layer1/layer2-end |- layer1-3) {};
  [continue chain=layer1]
  \chainin (a) [join=with layer1/layer2-end];
  \path
  node [block,join,minimum height=20] {}
  node [block,join] {}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mixed nodes in chains]

Note that the `chains` implementation is a little ... eccentric ... at times. As I understand it, it is considered deprecated and, hence, very unlikely to get significant improvements.

[I think this is a shame because the idea has a pleasing simplicity and is more friendly to beginners than the functionality provided by the `graphs` syntax, which replaces it. The `graphs` syntax is, however, more flexible, powerful and concise.]

Comment: (+1) ... for solution and special for your comments on the end. This good to know! Chains serve me very well ...

Comment: It's interesting. I never used `on grid` that I remember. I'm always curious to see what other people use.

Comment: Accepted because - although it does not directly answer the question *why* the offset is there - it points to the superceding `graphs` syntax and points out `chains`' excentricity. Thanks also for the branching demo; despite the unfortunate lengthening of the node names (`layer1/layer2-end`), this looks like a good match.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand question correctly, than you looking for something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1,
  block/.style={
    on chain,
    inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    draw,minimum height=10,minimum width=2}
                    ]
\path[start chain=layer1]
  node[block] {}
  node[block,join] {}
  node[block,join] {};
\path[start chain=layer2]
  node[block,join=with layer1-end,below=of layer1-end] {}
  node[block,join] {}
  node[block,join] {};
\path[continue chain=layer1]   
  node[block,join=with layer2-end,above=of layer2-end] {}% <--
  node[block,join] {}
  node[block,join] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

As you see, in continuation I use the same syntax as you for draw chain `layer2`. Options `continue chain=...` means that the chain will continue, where you indicate, in this case above of end node in `chain2`.

Main benefits to use of chains is relative positioning of nodes: next node in chain is always placed relatively to node before it.

**Addendum:** 
From comments can be concluded, that you looking for nodes on the grid:

[image]

New MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    on grid,
  node distance=2cm and 0.5 cm,
  block/.style={
    on chain,
    inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    draw,minimum height=#1,minimum width=2}
                    ]
\path[start chain=layer1]
  node[block=1cm] {}
  node[block=2cm,join] {}
  node[block=1cm,join] {};
\path[start chain=layer2]
  node[block=1cm,join=with layer1-end,below=of layer1-end] {}
  node[block=1cm,join] {}
  node[block=1cm,join] {};
\path[continue chain=layer1]
  node[block=2cm,join=with layer2-end,above=of layer2-end] {}% <--
  node[block=1cm,join] {}
  node[block=1cm,join] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's actually what I started with. I am sorry; the MWE no longer shows that I cannot use `above=of ...`, because in general (with varying block heights), it does not give you aligned nodes on layer1. I will add that constraint to the question. Since I managed to work around the problem by using two chains, the question really is, *why* do I need to do that?

Comment: Well, my crystal ball is recently fogy, so I can't see, what is your problem :-). As I now understand, you need to employ "on grid" option. See my edit of answer ...